# How to add functional code inside the Render function - React JS

Tags: reactjs

Below is my Render logic, I'm trying to run the loop inside the fieldset, but I'm getting syntax error

```
Parsing error: '}' expected.eslint
```

please help

```
  const renderComponentButtons = () => {
    const { questionNo } = componentContent;
    if (componentContent?.button) {
      return (
        <fieldset className="col-lg-8" aria-labelledby={componentContent?.ariaLabelledby}>
          {
            Object.keys(componentContent.button).map((key) => {
              <ButtonAction
                key={key}
                data-testid="getDisputeQst1"
                onClick={() => {
                  return (componentContent.button[key]?.displayModal === 'True')
                    ? openModalWindow(questionNo, key) : moveToNextQuestion(componentContent.button[key].buttonText);
                }}
              >
                {componentContent.button[key].buttonText}
              </ButtonAction>
            });
          }
        </fieldset>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };
```

Comment: Which line are you seeing the error on? (Also, you don't return anything from your `Object.keys(componentContent.button).map(...)`)

Comment: `});` this semikoli is wrong inside an expression

Answer (score 0):

You replace return null to return ""

```
 const renderComponentButtons = () => {
  const { questionNo } = componentContent;
  if (componentContent?.button) {
    return (
      <fieldset className="col-lg-8" aria-labelledby= 
         {componentContent?.ariaLabelledby}>
         {
          Object.keys(componentContent.button).map((key) => {
          <ButtonAction
          key={key}
          data-testid="getDisputeQst1"
          onClick={() => {
            return (componentContent.button[key]?.displayModal === 'True')
              ? openModalWindow(questionNo, key) : 
             moveToNextQuestion(componentContent.button[key].buttonText);
          }}
        >
          {componentContent.button[key].buttonText}
        </ButtonAction>
        });
       }
     </fieldset>
      ); 
     }
   return {foo:"bar"};
  };
```

Comment: How would this help? (And your explanation doesn't match your code)

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine to me. You are missing to return the component inside your arrow function though.

`return (<ButtonAction>{...}</ButtonAction>)`

Like it is now it returns `undefined`.

If you use `()=>{}` it will return `undefined` unless you use `return` keyword.

But you can use an arrow function without curly braces and it will return the value after the `=>` arrow. Best practice is to also use round brackets for the return value

`() => (<ButtonAction/>)`

You can also return objects like this

`()=>({foo:"bar"})`

is the same as

`()=>{ return {foo:"bar"} }`

Maybe worthwhile for you to check the docs about arrow functions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

```
const renderComponentButtons = () => {
const { questionNo } = componentContent;
if (componentContent?.button) {
  return (
    <fieldset className="col-lg-8" aria-labelledby={componentContent?.ariaLabelledby}>
      {
        Object.keys(componentContent.button).map((key) => {
          <ButtonAction
            key={key}
            data-testid="getDisputeQst1"
            onClick={() => {
              return (componentContent.button[key]?.displayModal === 'True')
                ? openModalWindow(questionNo, key) : moveToNextQuestion(componentContent.button[key].buttonText);
            }}
          >
            {componentContent.button[key].buttonText}
          </ButtonAction>
        })
      }
    </fieldset>
  );
}
else
{
  return null;

}
};
```